# Instantiating nested class within static class

Tags: c#, static, nested

I'm currently trying to manage the different REST-services I'm using in my project, which I have done by having one static class as a container class, followed up by several nested classes, like this:

```
public static class HostName {
    private const string HostAddress = "https://rest.connection.string/api"
    public class CourseQueryInformation{
        public CourseQueryInformation(string par, string par2)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public class PersonQueryInformation{
        public CourseQueryInformation(string par, string par2)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now my main problem is that in order to instantiate a new object, I have to do the following:

```
var typeofobj = new HostName.CourseQueryInformation("par","parer");
```

This feels a bit messy.

So, my main question is, is there any way to do this in a cleaner way? I would really like to keep the classes sorted within a container, but I'm uncertain if this is the best approach.

Comment: Please post some actual code, the things you've posted looks like methods without return types but you call them classes, can you add the missing bits? A class does not have parameters. Also, why doesn't just a namespace suffice?

Comment: Sorry, the example is wrong. Editing!

Comment: Why do you abuse a static class as "container", when that is exactly what namespaces are for?

Comment: I definitely need to work on my example-making-skills, but in this example, the parent class has one constant private property which is shared with the underlying classes. It contains the base-url for the REST-service where the child-classes are constructing the rest of the REST-Url. Edited the example now. No abuse intended!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use inheritance and a namespace should do the work as explained here  : [inheritance and nameSpaces](http://www.functionx.com/csharp2/classes2/abstraction.htm)

it should be like that

```
 namespace Hosting
{
    class Host //could be abstract also
    {   
        private string _hostAddress = "foo";
        get { return _hostAddress; }


    }

    public class CourseQueryInformation : Host
    {
        public CourseQueryInformation(string par, string par2)
            {
                ...
            }
    }


    public class PersonQueryInformation : Host
    {
        public PersonQueryInformation(string par, string par2)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

if you use inheritance, you can also add all what is in common with your subClasses, then get a maintainable code that respect the OO paradigm, playin with inheritance and polymorphism

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with the way you are calling it. As an alternative, you could utilize a factory pattern within HostName:

```
public static CourseQueryInformation CreateCourseQueryInformation(string par, string par2)
{
    return new CourseQueryInformation (par, par2);
}
```

and call it like:

```
var typeofobj = HostName.GetCourseQueryInformation("par","parer");
```

or use the namespace alias as Samyne suggessts:

```
using CourseQueryInformation = HostName.CourseQueryInformation;
var typeofobj = new CourseQueryInformation("par","parer");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the provided methods are an extention you can always use extention methods. Those work perfectly in static class.
Only add the namespace in the using above and you'll have acces to them. Just like linq does.

Otherwise you can use an alias for the class in the using namespace

```
using HNCourseQueryInformation = HostName.CourseQueryInformation;
```